# Error when calculating RHS of ode "no method matching Float64(::Num)"

Tags: julia

I have some code that uses a function to calculate some changes in concentration, but I get an error of:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Float64(::Num)
Closest candidates are:
  (::Type{T})(::Real, ::RoundingMode) where T<:AbstractFloat at rounding.jl:200
  (::Type{T})(::T) where T<:Number at boot.jl:760
  (::Type{T})(::AbstractChar) where T<:Union{AbstractChar, Number} at char.jl:50
```

I have attached a MWE below.
The code initializes some parameters, and uses the initialized parameters to calculate additional parameters (Ke and kb), then inputs these parameters into my function `oderhs(c,Ke,kb,aw,aw²,aw³,ρζ,ρζ²,ρζ³,γ,γ²)` which should return `dc` which is my solution vector that I require.

```
using DifferentialEquations
@parameters t c0[1:4] Ke[1:2] kb[1:2] aw aw² aw³ ρ ζ ρζ ρζ² γ γ² T

# Calculate parameters
ρ = 0.592
ζ = 1.0
ρζ  = ρ*ζ
ρζ² = ρζ*ρζ
ρζ³ = ρζ*ρζ²

aw = 0.995
aw² = aw*aw
aw³ = aw*aw²

γ = 1.08
γ² = γ*γ

T = 590.0
# calculate equilibrium constants
Ke[01] = (1.0E-06)*10.0^(-4.098 + (-3245.2/T) + (2.2362E+05/(T^2)) + (-3.9984E+07/(T^3)) + (log10(ρ) * (13.957 + (-1262.3/T) + (8.5641E+05/(T^2)))) )
Ke[02] = 10^(28.6059+0.012078*T+(1573.21/T)-13.2258*log10(T))

# calculate backward rate constants
kb[01] = Ke[01]*ρζ²/γ²
kb[02] = Ke[02]*γ/ρζ


# set initial concentrations
c0 = [0.09897, 0.01186, 2.94e-5, 4.17e-8]

function oderhs(c,Ke,kb,aw,aw²,aw³,ρζ,ρζ²,ρζ³,γ,γ²)
      # rename c to their corresponding species
      H₃BO₃   = c[1]; H₄BO₄⁻ = c[2]; OH⁻ = c[3]; H⁺ = c[4];
      # rename Ke to their corresponding reactions
      Ke_iw1 = Ke[1]; Ke_ba1 = Ke[2];
      # rename kb to their corresponding reactions
      kb_iw1 = kb[1]; kb_ba1 = kb[2];
      # determine the rate of reaction for each reaction
      r_iw1 = kb_iw1*(H⁺*OH⁻ - Ke_iw1*ρζ²*aw/γ²)
      r_ba1 = kb_ba1*(H₄BO₄⁻ - H₃BO₃*OH⁻*Ke_ba1*γ/ρζ)
      dc = zeros(eltype(c),4)
      # calculate the change in species concentration
      dc[1] = r_ba1
      dc[2] = r_ba1
      dc[3] = r_iw1 + r_ba1
      dc[4] = r_iw1
      
      return dc
end

dc = oderhs(c0,Ke,kb,aw,aw²,aw³,ρζ,ρζ²,ρζ³,γ,γ²)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zeros(eltype(c),4)` creates an Array of Float64, which isn't what you want because you're trying to create a symbolic version of the ODE equations (right? otherwise this doesn't make sense). Thus you want to this be like `zeros(Num,4)`, so that the return is the symbolic equations, and then you'd generate the actual code for DifferentialEquations.jl from the ModelingToolkit.jl `ODESystem`.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly!
btw my code is a modification of yours in https://github.com/SciML/ModelingToolkit.jl/blob/master/test/reactionsystem.jl line 38

Comment: oh man, that's an old old old test hehe, we should update that.